# Ionic Framework turn dark blank page

Tags: ionic-framework

right now i'm working ionic framework but it looks like my codes get errors , how to check and find my syntax error ? does ionic framework IDE to check syntax error like eclipse ?

Comment: Show the error please

Comment: i wanna create mobile web app likes here http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/JdtuG , but when i copy codes from that url to my ionic project, side menu is not working and sometimes become white/black screen